# how to reset value of array when dynamic value reaches to set limit?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to reset `$scope.event` to `[]` if `limit` is greater than `$scope.dynamic` , So below code is not reseting the value of `$scope.event` Any idea where i am making mistake ?

main.html

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event track by $index | limitTo:500" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

ctrl.js

```
 var limit = 5000;
 $scope.event = [];
 var totalLimit;
 $scope.dynamic = this numeric value is changing based on data;
socket.on('ditConsumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
        file: $scope.filename,
        data: data
    }
  getByteLen(data);
    safelyAdd({
        id: $scope.event.length,
        value: data
    });

});

function safelyAdd(element) {
    if (totalLimit > limit) {
        $scope.event = []; //reset array if max size reached..
    }
    $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..
    console.log('array', $scope.event);
    console.log('totalLimit', totalLimit);
}
```

getting `$scope.dynamic` value in these functions...

```
   $scope.random = function(value) {
        $scope.dynamic = value;
        totalLimit = value;
        $scope.downloadPercentage = parseFloat((value/$scope.maxBytes) * 100).toFixed(0);
        console.log('current value-dynamic',$scope.dynamic);
    };
    function getByteLen(normal_val) {
        // Force string type
        normal_val = String(normal_val);

        var byteLen = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < normal_val.length; i++) {
            var c = normal_val.charCodeAt(i);
            byteLen += c < (1 <<  7) ? 1 :
                c < (1 << 11) ? 2 :
                    c < (1 << 16) ? 3 :
                        c < (1 << 21) ? 4 :
                            c < (1 << 26) ? 5 :
                                c < (1 << 31) ? 6 : Number.NaN;
        }
        currentBytesSum =  currentFileBytes.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
        $scope.random(currentBytesSum);
        formatBytes(currentBytesSum);
        return byteLen;
    }
    function formatBytes(bytes,decimals) {
        if(bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
        var k = 1000;
        var dm = decimals + 1 || 3;
        var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
        var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
        var data = parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        console.log('sum of all the bytes', data);
        $scope.currentBytes = data;
    }
```

Comment: what does `console.log('array', $scope.event);` output?

Comment: Why don't you put a `console.log(limit + ' | ' + $scope.dynamic)` inside safelyAdd and see what the values are.

Comment: `$scope.event` value printed array of object that should reset if it reaches `limit`

Comment: Why manage the size of the array via `$scope.dynamic`? you should check the array size via `$scope.event.length`.You probably have a global scoping issue but we cannir see that as you did not include your code that is changing `$scope.dynamic`

Comment: so idea is to purge old data in array once it reaches certain limit because it was creating performance issue and freezing the screen. we receiving 5000 messages in one minute so we want to have string size in bytes and when `$scope.event` array object byte size reaches `limit` it should reset the `$scope.event`.

Comment: added function how i am getting `$scope.dynamic` value

Comment: are you using $scope.dynamic in many controllers?

Comment: `$scope.dynamic` functions are in same controller and we are only using in one controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var limit = 5000;
$scope.dynamic = 0;
var totalReceived = 0;

socket.on('ditConsumer', function (data) {
    var byteLength = getByteLen(data);
    $scope.dynamic += byteLength;
    totalReceived += byteLength;

    $scope.$apply(function() {
        safelyAdd({
            id: $scope.event.length,
            value: data
        });
    });

});

function safelyAdd(element) {
    if (received > limit) {
        $scope.event = []; //reset array if max size reached..
        $scope.dynamic = 0;
    }
    $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..
    console.log('array', $scope.event);
    console.log('totalLimit', totalLimit);
}

$scope.random = function (value) {
    $scope.downloadPercentage = parseFloat((value / $scope.maxBytes) * 100).toFixed(0);
    console.log('current value-dynamic', $scope.dynamic);
};
function getByteLen(normal_val) {
    // Force string type
    normal_val = String(normal_val);

    var byteLen = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < normal_val.length; i++) {
        var c = normal_val.charCodeAt(i);
        byteLen += c < (1 << 7) ? 1 :
                c < (1 << 11) ? 2 :
                        c < (1 << 16) ? 3 :
                                c < (1 << 21) ? 4 :
                                        c < (1 << 26) ? 5 :
                                                c < (1 << 31) ? 6 : Number.NaN;
    }
    currentBytesSum = currentFileBytes.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    formatBytes(currentBytesSum);
    return byteLen;
}

function formatBytes(bytes, decimals) {
    if (bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    var k = 1000;
    var dm = decimals + 1 || 3;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    var data = parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
    console.log('sum of all the bytes', data);
    $scope.currentBytes = data;
}
```

Comment: but problem is after reseting array `$scope.dynamic` will be always greater and it will never met the condition.

Comment: @how is `$scope.dynamic` calculated?

Comment: `$scope.dynamic` is value coming from another function that is converting string to bytes and it will change consistently and adds up  everytime  new message recieved, so its basically is sum of bytes total messages recieved so far..

Comment: @hussain, you probably need to compare like this `if ($scope.dynamic > limit) {         $scope.event = []; $scope.dynamic = 0; }`

Comment: but i also need `$scope.dynamic` value to keep sum for other scenario if we set `$scope.dynamic`  to 0 it break some other logic, is there way we can reset `$scope.dynamic` only when it check limit ?

Comment: @hussain, maybe use other variable?

Comment: I think we are close i created new variable `totalLimit` and assign sum of bytes to `totalLimit` first time it works when it reaches to 5000 it reset the array but after that it only display one object in aray and totalLimit value is always 0. Any idea what is wrong here question updated ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125752/discussion-between-maximus-and-hussain).

Answer (score 1):

Now that you updated your code, I understand now that $scope.dynamic and totalLength are both meant to contain the current size in bytes of the $scope.event array (not to exceed 5000 bytes) rather than the array length as I previously thought. It appears you have a lot of variables living in the global scope that could get overwritten elsewhere in the application, so that is a possibility. Can you publish some of your console.log statements? Aside from that, did you try adding .bind(this) to the ditConsumer callback?

```
socket.on('ditConsumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
        file: $scope.filename,
        data: data
    }
    getByteLen(data);
    safelyAdd({
        id: $scope.event.length,
        value: data
    });

}.bind(this));
```

Comment: `$scope.dyamic` value is sum and  will change everytime  we recieve message.